# C# checking if a table exists in a database or not

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in the same database in SQL Server 2008. I want to copy contents of a table to another empty table having same schema, but when I execute the statement

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.leadmasters", myConnection);
```

it throws an error saying the table already exists in the database.

I want that if the table already exists, the table should be deleted because the above SQL query creates the table and copies the contents to it.

Please suggest

My code is

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("File Name=E:\\Vivek\\ImplementUdl\\ImplementUdl\\new.udl");

     try
     {
         myConnection.Open();

         if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            MessageBox.Show("Connection opened successfully!");
         else
            MessageBox.Show("Connection could not be established");

         DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.leadmasters", myConnection);

         da.Fill(ds);

         MessageBox.Show("Data Copied!!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
           myConnection.Close();
     }

     return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use temporary table instead of real one? i.e. `dbo.#leadmastersnew`. It will be visible only in the scope of your connection and dropped automatically on connection close.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Good Idea but how do I implement it.? I am new to c#

Comment: As I've mentioned above - you should just table name preceeded by `#`, for example, `dbo.#leadmastersnew`. By the way - it is not c# feature, but sql server's one.

Comment: @AndyKorneyevThanks for the reply.But what is to be done if the table already exists and I want to add data to it without deleting the table?.This is just another doubt.Hope you dont mind

Comment: Temporary table can't exists if you doesn't created it while your connection is open. And it will be dropped by server when your connection will be closed. So, if you open your connection - you can be sure that no `dbo.#leadmastersnew` table exists until you call something like `select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.#leadmasters`, and you don't need to delete it.

Comment: However, if you prefer not to use temporary tables, and only want to insert into existed table without deleting it - you should use something like `insert into dbo.leadmastersnes (column1, column2 etc...) select value1, value2 etc... from dbo.leadmasters` instead of your query, as `select ... into tablexxx` implicitly creates `tablexxx` table.

Comment: Thanks @AndyKorneyev but the scenario is such that I already have an empty table in the database to which I want to add the the data from another table of the same schema.What is to be done in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62182/discussion-between-user2614235-and-andy-korneyev).

Comment: @user2614235 If you an answer suits your needs accept it as such

Answer (score 2):

I would create an empty table if it doesn't exist yet and then copy in the data. If possible don't use udl files for connections, but store the connection string elsewhere

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("<connectionstring>"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                if object_id('dbo.leadmastersnew') is null
                  begin
                      select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.leadmasters where 1=2
                      alter table dbo.leadmastersnew add primary key (<key>)
                  end
                insert into dbo.leadmastersnew
                select * 
                from dbo.leadmasters lm
                where not exists(select * from dbo.leadmastersnew lmn where lm.<key> = lmn.<key>)", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

note that in the where clause you need to fill out the correct `<key>` columns. I also added a primary key constraint to the new table as select into will not copy the primary key/indexes of the source table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined just to do it all in a single SQL Statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.leadmastersnew', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.leadmastersnew;

SELECT  * 
INTO    dbo.leadmastersnew 
FROM    dbo.leadmasters;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But what is to be done if the table already exists and I want to add data to it without deleting the table?.This is just another doubt.Hope you dont mind

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem might be with this query

```
EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
```

After that, if it returns True then the table exists. Now you need to run an insertion query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.The_table(id,username,password,email) VALUES(@id,@username,@password, @email)";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db.Connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@id","abc");
command.Parameters.Add("@username","abc");
command.Parameters.Add("@password","abc");
command.Parameters.Add("@email","abc");

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If the original statement returns false you need to run a create table query before runnig the insert query. The create table query looks a lot like this.

```
string queryString =  @"
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   Id  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Name        varchar(50) 
)";


    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        queryString, connection);

    command.ExecuteNonReader();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But what is to be done if the table already exists and I want to add data to it without deleting the table?.This is just another doubt.Hope you dont mind

Comment: You want to empty it and add new data or append data to it?

Comment: @user2614235 What is your exact request? If the table exists, empty it and add new data? or If the table exists insert this new data that I have while also preserving the old?

Comment: John if the table exists ,the 2nd one.I want to insert data in that table

Comment: Well you can simply run the first query, check if it exists and then run a second query inserting data to the existing table. Would you like me to edit my answer with the INSERT query?

Comment: If you like an answer and it completely suits your needs accept it as the proper answer for the question (the tick on the side)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question of why the SQL won't work, the reason you get an error is because you have the following:

```
select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.leadmasters
```

SQL interprets that as a command to create the table `leadmastersnew` and then populates it. If you are set on using the solution you have then simply change your SQL to the following:

```
if object_id('dbo.leadmastersnew') is not null begin drop table dbo.leadmastersnew end select * into dbo.leadmastersnew from dbo.leadmasters
```

This will test to see if the table exists, drop it if so then create and populate the table again. It's not a terribly clean way to do things but if that's what you want then this will do it.